# Is there a way to transpose data using Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following input data

a   b  c

6   1  2

6   3  5

4   2  7

4   9  8

Want to apply transformations on the data using pig to get the following output

6   4

1    2

2    7

3    9

5    8

Please let me know how this can be done using pig statements. 
Is there any function in pig for transpose (to convert rows to columns and column as rows)

Comment: I cannot understand how those two sets of numbers are connected, but for what it's worth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498657/how-do-i-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-pig

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus Although his question is incredibly unclear he appears to be ocnsidering the first 2 rows as a single row, and the second two rows as a single row. If I am correct then the question should read input: `6 1 2 4 2 7 || 6 3 5 4 9 8`. He also appears to be only selecting distinct pairs, so the second `6 4` pair is not showing up. I'll submit an edit to that extent in a sec.