# How to transpose columns to rows in pig

Tags: apache-pig, transpose

Please can any one help me to write code to perform transpose operation in Pig.

Input file

```
1,2 
3,4  
5,6
```

Output file

```
1,3,5
2,4,6
```

Comment: do you want to transpose the data or move every thing in a single tuple?

transposing the data will make it look like {(1,3,5),(2,4,6)}.

Comment: I wann get rows as columns .

Comment: Take a look at this [how to do Transpose in corresponding few columns in pig/hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492700/how-to-do-transpose-in-corresponding-few-columns-in-pig-hive)

Comment: You can see these urls for help: [how-do-i-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-pig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498657/how-do-i-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-pig)

Comment: Tried with above mentioned  answers  but still nt up to my  required output.why transpose function will nt give desired output?